# List comprehension of lambdas generates identical functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, list-comprehension

I want a list of functions where the `i`th function takes a vector as input and returns the `i`th element of that vector

```
n_functions = 10
func_list = [lambda z: z[i], for i in range(n_functions)]
```

However these are, for some reason, all identical functions of the form `lambda z: z[n_functions-1]` since the code below gives `[9 9 ... 9]`

```
func_values = [f(range(10)) for f in func_list]
```

What am I doing wrong? I writing `(lambda z: z[i])` in the list comprehension but nothing changes.

Comment: `func_list = [lambda z, i=i: z[i] for i in range(n_functions)]`